# Locally exposable points under biholomorphisms are still locally exposable

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $\Omega\subset\subset\Bbb C^n$ and let $\zeta_0\in K:=\overline\Omega$ be *locally exposable* with respect to $\rho$, meaning that:

$\bullet\;\;\rho(\zeta_0)=0\;;$

$\bullet\;\; d\rho(\zeta_0)\neq0\;;$

$\bullet\;\;\rho<0$ on $U\cap K\setminus\{\zeta_0\}$ for some $U\subset\Bbb C^n$ open neighborhood of $\zeta_0$,

where $\rho\colon V\to\Bbb R$ is a $\mathscr C^2-$smooth strictly plurisubharmonic function on $V$, that is
$$
L_a(\rho;t):=\sum_{j,k=1}^n\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial z_j\partial\overline z_k}(a)t_j\overline t_k>0\;\;\;\forall t\in\Bbb C^n,\;t\neq0,\;a\in V,
$$
being $V\subset\Bbb C^n$ open neighborhood of $K$.

Let $Y$ be a complex manifold with $m:=\dim Y>n$ (we can think $Y=\Bbb C^m$) and consider
$$
g\colon V\to Y
$$
holomorphic injective. I want to prove that $\zeta_1:=g(\zeta_0)$ locally exposable with respect to $K_1:=g(K)$, but I'm struggling in finding a suitable $\rho_1$ *strictly* psh. In the case $m=n$ I could consider $\rho_1:=\rho\circ g^{-1}$, but when $m>n$ then $g^{-1}$ is defined and holomorphic on $g(V)$ which is **NOT** open in $Y$. In general it doesn't seem possible to proceed in this direction, since, given $D\subset Y$ open and $\alpha\colon D\to V$ holomorphic, it is well known that $\rho\circ\alpha$ is plurisubharmonic, in fact a direct computation shows that
$$
L_w(\rho\circ\alpha;t)=L_{\alpha(w)}(\rho;\alpha'(w)t)\ge0\;\;,\;\forall t\in\Bbb C^m\;\;,\;w\in D\;,
$$
but the assumption $m>n$ implies that $\ker\alpha'(a)$ is nontrivial for all $a$, hence we deduce that $\rho\circ\alpha$ is **never** strictly plurisubharmonic.

So, again, how can I prove that $\zeta_1$ is locally exposable, finding some strictly psh function?

---

**EDIT:** I kept thinking and I am almost there, I kindly need two hints. For a certain reason, I need $K_1$ to be Stein compact; by Theorem 1.2 in [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.2112.pdf) (reported in [Forstneric's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-22250-4) in Theorem 3.2.1) the compact $K_1$ is a Stein compact if it is a *complex subvariety*, that is, around every point, it is the zero set of a certain number of holomorphic functions: for every $w\in K_1$ there exists $A\subset\Bbb C^m$ neighborhood of $w$ and $f_1,\dots,f_N\in\mathcal O(A)$ such that
$$
K_1\cap A=\{z\in A\;:\;f_1(z)=\cdots=f_N(z)=0\}\;.
$$
Set now
$$
h(z,w):=g(w)-z\;,\;\;(z,w)\in \Bbb C^m\times U\;
$$
which is holomorphic, $h(\zeta_1,\zeta_0)=0$ and $\partial_w h(\zeta_1,\zeta_0)=dg(\zeta_0)$ has maximum rank if $\zeta_0$ is a regular point, so we can apply IFT, getting $A\subset\Bbb C^m$ nhbd of $\zeta_1$, $B\subset U$ nhbd of $\zeta_0$ and $\varphi\colon A\to B$ holomorphic such that
$$
h(z,\varphi(z))=0\;\;\forall z\in A\;,
$$
that is
$$
g(\varphi(z))-z=0\;\;\forall z\in A\;
$$
and single out the components:
$$
f_j(z):=g_j(\varphi(z))-\pi_j(z)\;,\;j=1,\dots,m\;.
$$
Then
$$
K_1\cap A=\{z\in A\;:\;f_1(z)=\cdots=f_m(z)=0\}\;,
$$
which is *almost* what I want; we worked around $\zeta_1$, but the same argument holds for any other regular point, and here comes my **first question**: is it possible to repeat the argument for a singular point? In this way I could conclude that $K_1$ is indeed a subvariety (and subsequently a Stein compact, as already pointed out).

Next, it is clear that
$$
\rho_1:=\rho\circ\varphi+\sum_{j=1}^m|f_j|^2
$$
is plurisubharmonic on $A$. As pointed out earlier, $\rho\circ\varphi$ is never strictly psh at $\zeta_1$. It's clear that $\rho_1(\zeta_1)=0$, with a computation one sees that $d\rho_1(\zeta_1)\neq0$ and $\rho_1<0$ on $A\cap K_1\setminus\{\zeta_1\}$, so in order to have $\zeta_1$ locally exposable in $K_1$ with respect to $\rho_1$ one needs to check that $\rho_1$ is actually *strictly* plurisubharmonic at $\zeta_1$. So here we focus on the sum $\sum_{j=1}^m|f_j|^2$, this would be strictly psh if the differentials of $f_j$ at $\zeta_1$ span the cotangent space. Even less is enough: whenever $t\in\ker\varphi'(\zeta_1)$, then $\sum_{j=1}^mL_{\zeta_1}(|f_j|^2;t)>0\;$. I suspect it is kinda straightforward to prove this and I'm just a bit confused. So this is the **second hint** I was asking for.

Comment: The condition of being locally exposable depends on the point $\zeta_0$ and on $K$. With respect to which compact set in $Y$ should $\zeta_1$ be locally exposable, and why do you expect it to be the case?

Comment: @RichardLärkäng: you are right, with respect to $K_1=g(K)$, see edit. Thanks. It works in the case $m=n$, I thought it could have worked for $m>n$ as well, but I might be wrong. Anyhow it would be nice to understand why the downvote, whoever it was.